# Do I really have to cast float to uint8_t if I just want to convert 203.0 to 203 at a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, typecast

In computers, it's OK to use `float` as an argument where the argument should actually be a `uint8_t`

```
void myFunction(uint8_t myVal);
```

But what if I call this function `myFunction(value);` where `value` is of datatype `float` inside a microcontroller? The microcontroller have single precision included. The variable `value` have its range from 0 to 250 in this case.

Do I need to call my function `myFunction((uint8_t) value)` ?

Comment: Did you try it? Why would compiling for microcontrollers be any different from compiling for computers?

Comment: @Justme No errors when I compile. But even if the compiler don't yell at me, it does not need it's safe. Microcontrollers are very sensitive and need to have correct instructions from the user.

Comment: So do computers, no difference there. If that works on PC it must work on MCU too.

Comment: @Daniel following up, when you compiled it, did you attempt to either inspect the resulting assembly or test the program with an appropriate debugger? If so, please include those details in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do explicit cast, the compiler knows what to do implicitly, just like when you assign the float to an integer variable for example.